# How to set the Kubectl from local computer to the minikube configured on DigitalOcean

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have setup minikube on centos on DigitalOcean. How can I  issue commands from my local installation of kubectl from my Windows terminal. I should be able to set the minikube and create pods from my local box.

Comment: Can you please explain what is it exactly that you want? It is not clear exactly from the question. You want to use you local `kubectl` against cluster (in this case minikube) in DO?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can configure minikube on digital ocean or any cloud provider because it needs the virtual box or any other hypervisor.
What you might have done is you might have installed mikrok8s which is ubuntu solution for single node kuberentes cluster.